# Why are there different versions of what Chazon Ish says is the size of an Amah?

Tags: number, shiurim-measurements, mathematics, chazon-ish, calculation

Different sources have different information regarding the size of an Amah (all measurements are attributed to Chazon Ish):

- [Halachipedia](https://halachipedia.com/index.php?title=Reference_of_Measurements_in_Halacha#Length) - 24 in. / 60.96 cm
- [Dafyomi.co.il](https://www.dafyomi.co.il/general/info/units-of-measurement.pdf) - 22.72 in. / 57.72 cm
- [Daat.ac.il](http://www.daat.ac.il/daat/toshba/tavla-2.htm) - 22.68 in. / 57.6 cm
- Artscroll "Gateway To The Talmud" - 22.8 in. / 58 cm
- [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Biblical_and_Talmudic_units_of_measurement#Discrepancies_of_ell) - 22.56 in. / 57.3 cm (although 57.6 cm if multiply from Etzbah)
- Steinsaltz Talmud Guide - 22.7 in. / 57.6 cm

I believe the source of the Chazon Ish's opinion is [OC Moed 39 - Kuntres Hashiurim](https://www.hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=14336&st=&pgnum=117). My Hebrew is not great, but it seems to mention 58 cm a few times throughout.

**Why do so many sources have different numbers for the same authority's opinion? Which source has the most reliable information that goes in accordance with what the Chazon Ish says?**

Comment: I'd guess it has to do with rounding a smaller unit (tefach? etzba?) and then multiplying up to an ammah.

Comment: @DoubleAA Thanks for the response. There are multiple versions for *etzbah* as well: 2.4cm (Daat, Wikipedia), 2.405 (DAF), 2.413 (Artscroll), and 2.54 (Halachipedia). Halachipedia seems to be far off from the others and 2.4 could be a rounding result. If rounding errors are causing the issue, I think Artscroll is most plausible, but I'd like to figure out what Chazon Ish actually said.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In the Steipler's Shiurin shel Torah he writes the Chazon Ish's opinion about the amount needed for each Mitzvah. When it is a Mitzva D'Oraisa like Sukkah, he uses 10cm as a Tefach - 60cm as an amah [image], but when it is a question of a D'Rabannan as seen in the topic of Ma'aka/fence on a roof (in a D'Rabbanan situation b'shas ha'dchak) he uses 9.6cm as a tefach - 57cm as an amah [image: he uses 9.6cm as a tefach - 57cm as an amah].

Comment: Thanks for explaining the source! Do you have an idea how the numbers such as the commonly seen 57.6cm and Artscroll's 58cm came about?

Comment: @eyl327 If you round off 9.62 to 9.6, times 6 = 57.6, and if you round off 9.82 to 9.8, times 6 = 58.8.

Comment: Shame they don't cover sig-figs in semicha classes